# how to write hql query for hibernate OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following classes laid out like so:

```
class User {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<UserRole> userRoles;
}

class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String role;
   }
```

I'm attempting to query for users that have a specific role (in this case, all users with the role ROLE_ADMIN), using the following query:

```
    org.hibernate.query.Query<User> userQuery=session.createQuery("from User as mc where mc.userRoles in (from UserRole as ur where ur.role in (:uRoles))",User.class);
    Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
    roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
    userQuery.setParameterList("uRoles", roles);
    List<User> admins = userQuery.getResultList();
```

However, the query is not returning any results.

Comment: `Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();` what is the use of roles here? And where `userRoles` argument came from ?

Comment: userRoles was a typo. Sorry. `Set<String> roles` holds a list of all roles that  I am searching for in this specific case it's just ROLE_ADMIN but it could be ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_WRITER for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session.createQuery(
  "from User as user join user.userRoles as userRole where userRole.role in :roles")
  .setParameter("roles", Arrays.asList("ROLE_ADMIN"))
  .getResultList();
```

Comment: I want to use a list because I might do something like                                             `Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
 roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");                                    roles.add("ROLE_WRITER");                                   roles.add("ROLE_READER");`

Comment: @AHAW Updated the answer.